# Tweepy get Tweets related to a specific country

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

**Context**

I am working on a topic modeling for twitter project.
The idea is to retrieve all tweets related to a specific country and analyze them in order to discover what people from a specific country are talking about on Twitter.

**What I have tried**

**1.First Solution**

I know that we can use twitter streaming API or cursor to retrieve tweets from a specific country and I have tried the following code to get all tweets given geocodes coordinates of a country.

I have written the following code :

```
def get_tweets(query_fname, auth, max_time, location=None):
    stop = datetime.now() + max_time
    twitter_stream = Stream(auth, CustomListener(query_fname))
    while datetime.now() < stop:
        if location:
            twitter_stream.filter(locations=[11.94,-13.64,30.54,5.19], is_async=True)
        else:
            twitter_stream.filter(track=query, is_async=True)
```

**The problem of this approach**

1. Not everyone has allowed Twitter to access his location details and with this approach, I can only get a few tweets something like 300 tweets for my location.
2. There are some persons who are not in the country but who tweet about the country and people within the country replies to them. Their tweets are not captured by this approach.

**2.Second Solution**

Another approach was to collect tweets with hashtags related to a country with a cursor

I have tried this code :

```
def query_tweet(client, query=[], max_tweets=2000, country=None):
    """
    query tweets using the query list pass in parameter
    """
    query = ' OR '.join(query)
    name = 'by_hashtags_'
    now = datetime.now()
    today = now.strftime("%d-%m-%Y-%H-%M")
    with open('data/query_drc_{}_{}.jsonl'.format(name, today), 'w') as f:
        for status in Cursor(
                client.search,
                q=query,
                include_rts=True).items(max_tweets):
            f.write(json.dumps(status._json) + "\n")
```

**Problem**

This approach gives more results than the first one but as you may notice, not everyone uses those hashtags to tweets about the country.

**3.Third approach**

I have tried to retrieve the tweet using place id specific to a country but it gives the same problem as the first approach.

**My questions**

- How can I retrieve all tweets about a specific country? I mean everything people are tweeting about for a specific country with or without country-specific hashtags?

Hint: For people who are not located in the country, It may be a good idea to get their tweets if they were replied or retweeted by people within the country.

Regards.

Comment: The fundamental problem here is that only a small number of Tweets carry geo information and therefore it will never be possible to find “all the Tweets related to a specific country”. You will only ever get a subset. That’s just a fact. Only 1-2% of all Tweets are geotagged - there’s no way to magically change that.